# (2+1)-d Unitary irreducible representations of the Poincare group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory

I am currently working through [this](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.525524) paper on relativistic field theories in three dimensions. I have come to terms with the classification of Unitary irreducible representations (UIR's) given. The problem I am now trying to solve is the explicit realisation of the physical UIR's (corresponding to steps 4 and 5 in Binegar's program). I would be very happy with an answer/guidance for either of my questions, you need not answer both.

**First** of all, I have an issue with step 5 of his program:

"Finally, from each UIR $\mathcal{D}[~~]$ of each stability subgroup $S_{\hat{O}}$ we form the induced UIR of $\pi_+^{~~\uparrow}$ (connected component of the Poincare group) given by 
$$U_{D}^{~\hat{O}}(a,\Lambda)\psi(p)=\exp(ip_{\mu}a^{\mu})\mathcal{D}[\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)]\psi(p) \tag{1}$$
where $\Omega(p)\in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to a Lorentz transformation which takes the momentum $p$ (on mass shell with mass m) to the stability point $\hat{p}$ (both momentum 3-vectors), $\Omega_{\Lambda}\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ and $\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is to be interpreted as its ($\Lambda$'s) projection onto the stability subgroup $S_{\hat{O}}$."

Now shouldn't $\Omega(p)$ in $\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)\equiv W(\Lambda,p)$ correspond to a Lorentz transformation which takes $\hat{p}$ to $p$ (not the other way around)? Otherwise I do not see how $W(\Lambda,p)$ can be an element of the stability group of $\hat{p}$. Observe that if this were the case then
$$\begin{align}W(\Lambda,p)\cdot \hat{p}&=\bigg(\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)\bigg)[\hat{p}^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}]\bigg(\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)\bigg)^T\\
&=\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{\Lambda}\bigg(\Omega(\Lambda^{-1}p)[\hat{p}^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}]\Omega^T(\Lambda^{-1}p)\bigg)\Omega^T_{\Lambda}\Omega^{-1T}(p)\\
&=\Omega^{-1}(p)\bigg(\Omega_{\Lambda}[(\Lambda^{-1}p)^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}]\Omega^T_{\Lambda}\bigg)\Omega^{-1T}(p)\\
&=\Omega^{-1}(p)[p^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}]\Omega^{-1T}(p)\\
&=\hat{p}^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}\\
&=\text{Id}\cdot\hat{p}
\end{align}$$
Where $p^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}$ is a symmetric 2x2 matrix given in the introduction and $\cdot$ denotes the action of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is unlikely that he wrote it wrong because he writes it in the same way multiple times throughout the paper (not to mention that this paper has ~ 350 citations). So *how should I be interpreting $W(\Lambda,p)$?*

**Second**ly, at the end of page 3/beginning of page 4 the author  derives some properties for these Wigner rotations, $W(\Lambda,p)$, for some specific orbits, viz., the (physical) massive and massless cases. For example, he claims that in the massive case for an infinitesimal rotation $R(\theta)$ we have
$$W(R(\theta),p)=\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{R(\theta)}\Omega(R^{-1}(\theta)p)=R(\theta)$$ 
and that for an infinitesimal boost $L(\vec{\theta})$ in the $\vec{\theta}$ direction,
$$W(L(\vec{\theta}),p)=\Omega^{-1}(p)\Omega_{L(\vec{\theta})}\Omega(L^{-1}(\vec{\theta})p)=R\bigg(\frac{\theta_1p_2-\theta_2p_1}{E+m}\bigg).$$
Given that the author does not supply a 'standard boost', or an $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix which corresponds to one (a.k.a an explicit $\Omega(p)$) for that matter, I would assume that there is a simple way to derive these relations. However I couldn't find such a simple method, and so I constructed a standard Lorentz transformation (SLT) which does the trick and was able to show the first and *almost* the second of these relations (after **alot** of cumbersome bookkeeping). The problem is that I think I should be using an $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ standard boost instead of a Lorentz standard boost, but it has proved extremely computationally expensive (and ugly) to obtain the $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix to which my SLT corresponds (not to mention there is that pesky $\pm$ uncertainty due to the double valued-ness of the double cover $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$). Furthermore, when trying to prove a similar relation (given just after these) for the massless case I think it is imperative to use an $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ boost rather than a Lorentz one, so I must conclude that my method is crap. Do you know of a better approach which I can take to proves these relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to questions:

1. The way I interpreted it is correct; $\Omega (p)$ should be an $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ matrix corresponding to a Lorentz transformation which takes the standard momentum $\hat{p}$ to $p$. In terms of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ transformations, this should be; $\Omega (p)\cdot\hat{p}=\Omega (p)\hat{p}^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}\Omega^T (p)=p^{\mu}\tau_{\mu}=\text{Id}\cdot p$.
2. Indeed, one has to use $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ transformations instead of Lorentz transformations since we are interested in projective (multi-valued) representations (one can go even farther and use the universal cover of the Lorentz group, which can be found [here](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.529994)). The relations stated at the end of the OP for the massive case can be proven using the following 'standard $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ boost':$$\Omega (p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m^2+2mE(\mathbf{p})}}
   \begin{pmatrix}m+E(\mathbf{p})-p^1&&p^2\\p^2&&m+E(\mathbf{p})+p^1\end{pmatrix}$$$$\text{ where }E(\mathbf{p})=\sqrt{m^2+(p^1)^2+(p^2)^2}.$$ Both proof's are very tedious, the second more so than the first. I used the universal cover of the Lorentz group to prove both, but it must be possible to do it by just considering $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ since it seems Binegar did it that way.  I am still working on the proof for the massless case.

In short, don't take Binegar's notation too seriously because it is ambiguous, inconsistent and incorrect on multiple accounts throughout the paper.